# Is $(x)$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It seems to me that it is as I can't think of another ideal that will 'contain' it apart from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ itself?

Comment: $R[x]/(x)\cong R$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $(2,x)$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 9):

Is $\mathbf Z$ a field? $                $

Answer (score 7):

No its not, remember that an ideal $I$ is maximal if and only if $A/I$ is a field, its easy to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ wich clearly is not a field.